# ORDER BY within JOIN

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to solve a little problem. Here's my query.

```
SELECT
    ud.user_details_id,
    IFNULL(ld.login_time, 'Never Logged In') AS login_time
FROM user_details AS ud
LEFT JOIN login_details AS ld ON ld.user_details_id = ud.user_details_id
WHERE ud.user_type_id = 1
GROUP BY ud.user_details_id
```

What I'm trying to do is get the last login time (or last record) from login_details table but I'm getting the first record for every player. Please guide.

Comment: try:
IFNULL(max(ld.login_time), 'Never Logged In') AS login_time

Comment: Wow, this was so simple * ***facepalm*** *